# How can I split a text file into multiple text files with specific names & contents?

Tags: text-processing

I have `file.txt` which contains content that follows this sort of style:

```
Target 99C - HJ Shove vs CO + SB SQ
[0.02]JdJh, JsJh, JcJh, JsJd, JcJd, JcJs, AhKh, AdKd, AsKs, AcKc[/0.02], [30.30]KdKh, KsKh, KcKh, KsKd, KcKd, KcKs[/30.30], [31.52]QdQh, QsQh, QcQh, QsQd, QcQd, QcQs[/31.52], [61.57]AdKh, AsKh, AcKh, AhKd, AsKd, AcKd, AhKs, AdKs, AcKs, AhKc, AdKc, AsKc[/61.57]

Target 100A - HJ Call vs BU + SB SQ
[0.01]Ah5h, Ad5d, As5s, Ac5c[/0.01], [0.06]KhTh, KdTd, KsTs, KcTc[/0.06], [0.13]JhTh, JdTd, JsTs, JcTc[/0.13], [0.43]AdAh, AsAh, AcAh, AsAd, AcAd, AcAs[/0.43], [0.59]7d7h, 7s7h, 7c7h, 7s7d, 7c7d, 7c7s[/0.59], [0.77]AhJh, AdJd, AsJs, AcJc[/0.77], [2.44]5d5h, 5s5h, 5c5h, 5s5d, 5c5d, 5c5s[/2.44], [7.06]6h5h, 6d5d, 6s5s, 6c5c[/7.06], [7.21]QdQh, QsQh, QcQh, QsQd, QcQd, QcQs[/7.21], [7.52]5h4h, 5d4d, 5s4s, 5c4c[/7.52], [8.69]KhJh, KdJd, KsJs, KcJc[/8.69], [9.89]6d6h, 6s6h, 6c6h, 6s6d, 6c6d, 6c6s[/9.89], [11.61]8d8h, 8s8h, 8c8h, 8s8d, 8c8d, 8c8s[/11.61], [11.73]9d9h, 9s9h, 9c9h, 9s9d, 9c9d, 9c9s[/11.73], [18.21]JdJh, JsJh, JcJh, JsJd, JcJd, JcJs[/18.21], [24.60]TdTh, TsTh, TcTh, TsTd, TcTd, TcTs[/24.60], [29.64]KhQh, KdQd, KsQs, KcQc[/29.64], AhQh, AdQd, AsQs, AcQc

Target 100B - HJ 4B to 29bb vs BU + SB SQ
[0.07]Ah6h, Ad6d, As6s, Ac6c[/0.07], [0.24]AhTh, AdTd, AsTs, AcTc[/0.24], [5.89]TdTh, TsTh, TcTh, TsTd, TcTd, TcTs[/5.89], [7.59]Kh9h, Kd9d, Ks9s, Kc9c[/7.59], [10.18]Ah3h, Ad3d, As3s, Ac3c[/10.18], [12.39]AdQh, AsQh, AcQh, AhQd, AsQd, AcQd, AhQs, AdQs, AcQs, AhQc, AdQc, AsQc[/12.39], [22.67]Kh7h, Kd7d, Ks7s, Kc7c[/22.67], [25.08]Kh6h, Kd6d, Ks6s, Kc6c[/25.08], [25.74]Kh8h, Kd8d, Ks8s, Kc8c[/25.74], [28.31]KhTh, KdTd, KsTs, KcTc[/28.31], [48.85]AdKh, AsKh, AcKh, AhKd, AsKd, AcKd, AhKs, AdKs, AcKs, AhKc, AdKc, AsKc[/48.85], [49.25]Ah5h, Ad5d, As5s, Ac5c[/49.25], [55.40]QdQh, QsQh, QcQh, QsQd, QcQd, QcQs[/55.40], [61.48]JdJh, JsJh, JcJh, JsJd, JcJd, JcJs[/61.48], [91.31]KhJh, KdJd, KsJs, KcJc[/91.31], [96.32]AhJh, AdJd, AsJs, AcJc[/96.32], [99.57]AdAh, AsAh, AcAh, AsAd, AcAd, AcAs[/99.57], [99.89]AhKh, AdKd, AsKs, AcKc[/99.89], [99.99]KdKh, KsKh, KcKh, KsKd, KcKd, KcKs[/99.99]

Target 100C - HJ Shove vs BU + SB SQ
[0.01]KdKh, KsKh, KcKh, KsKd, KcKd, KcKs[/0.01], [0.11]AhKh, AdKd, AsKs, AcKc[/0.11], [20.31]JdJh, JsJh, JcJh, JsJd, JcJd, JcJs[/20.31], [37.39]QdQh, QsQh, QcQh, QsQd, QcQd, QcQs[/37.39], [51.15]AdKh, AsKh, AcKh, AhKd, AsKd, AcKd, AhKs, AdKs, AcKs, AhKc, AdKc, AsKc[/51.15]

Target 101A - HJ Call vs CO + BU SQ
[0.08]5h4h, 5d4d, 5s4s, 5c4c[/0.08], [0.13]6h5h, 6d5d, 6s5s, 6c5c[/0.13], [0.56]TdTh, TsTh, TcTh, TsTd, TcTd, TcTs[/0.56], [0.71]QdQh, QsQh, QcQh, QsQd, QcQd, QcQs[/0.71], [1.75]8d8h, 8s8h, 8c8h, 8s8d, 8c8d, 8c8s[/1.75], [2.18]7d7h, 7s7h, 7c7h, 7s7d, 7c7d, 7c7s[/2.18], [3.68]9d9h, 9s9h, 9c9h, 9s9d, 9c9d, 9c9s[/3.68], [5.68]KhQh, KdQd, KsQs, KcQc[/5.68], [10.56]JdJh, JsJh, JcJh, JsJd, JcJd, JcJs[/10.56], [17.73]AhQh, AdQd, AsQs, AcQc[/17.73]
```

This file goes on for a while, containing a total of 300 'targets'. I want to split this file into ~300 files, so there will be a file named "HJ Call vs CO + BU SQ.txt" which contains all the content from "[0.08]" to "[/17.73]" inclusive.

I have looked at using csplit but this will not work as I'm pretty sure the names cannot be changed variably, I am considering grep & tee but again, I'm not sure this is the right approach. Is anyone familiar with a simple way to tackle this problem?

I am using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us an _actual_ example from your file. Make sure to include a few different cases. We need to know what the real format is in order to help. For example, can targets have more than one line of content? Can the word `Target` appear as the first word of a line that is not a header? Does the `-` appear in any lines other than the header? We need to know what is constant and what is variable in your file in order to help you parse it. Finally, please also tell us what operating system you are using, that is very relevant.

Comment: Edited to include actual example, turns out the content is all just in one line which makes things a lot easier.

I am using Windows 10 but I have Linux for Windows with Ubuntu and access to whatever VMs needed, but yeah - I have linux and windows CLI.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F ' - ' '/^Target/{fn=$2} !/^Target|^$/{print >> fn}' file.txt
```

- `-F ' - '` will let `awk` split on dash with surrounded spaces.
- `/^Target/{fn=$2}` Will set `fn` to the filename (second field)
- `!/^Target|^$/{print >> fn}` Will print contents of lines that do not match `^Target` or empty line (`^$`) to the filename.

As you use Windows, you might need to take care that your file has Unix line endings.

Comment: Thank you - this worked really well aside from a few small issues.

Comment: @user481575 If one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: One quick thing with @pLumo answer, the files when saved go along the format of:

"BU Call CO Open and Call SB SQ"
or
"BB Call vs UTG 2.5bb" - this saves as a "5bb" file.

Do you know how I could save all of these as just .txt's?

Comment: they're probably windows text files, with line-endings of CR+LF.  Unix text files have lines ending in LF only.   Try adding `-v RS='\r\n'` to the awk command line.  If you want windows style text output, add `-v ORS='\r\n'` too.

Comment: That is what I meant with the last sentence ;-) Thanks @cas

Answer (score 0):

`python` along with the `groupby` method from the `itertools` module.
The groupby method  takes two inputs , an iterator (in our case a file handle on the input file) and a function that tells groupby what to group on (in our case a lambda function that looks for empty lines)

```
dos2unix file

python3 -c 'import sys, itertools as it
ifile = sys.argv[1]
with open(ifile) as f:
  for k,igrp in it.groupby(f, lambda x: x == "\n"):
    if not k:
      G = list(igrp)
      outfile = G.pop(0).rstrip().split("-")[1].lstrip()+".txt"
      with open(outfile,"w") as fp:
        fp.writelines(G)
' file
```